# From MySQL to Postgres: Last Quarter Hour

Tags: mysql, postgresql, function, date, migration

I am migrating from MySQL to Postgres. I need to take a DateTime value (apparently timestamp in Postgres) and determine the last quarter hour value.
I have a solution in both environments, but I'm wondering if there is a more compact or elegant Postgres solution.
Here is my MySQL approach:

```
select cast(now() as date) + interval hour(now()) hour + interval (floor(minute(now()) / 15) * 15) minute as last_quarter_hour;
```

Here is my Postgres approach:

```
select date(current_timestamp) + date_part('hour',cast(current_timestamp as timestamp)) * interval '1 hour' + floor(date_part('minute',cast(current_timestamp as timestamp)) / 15) * 15 * interval '1 minute' as last_quarter_hour;
```

All suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit simpler:

```
select
    date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) +
    date_part('minute', current_timestamp)::int / 15 * interval '15 minute' as last_quarter_hour
```

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

So, may be not less code, but I think, this is little bit more  intuitive and readable solution.

```
SELECT CAST(
        SUBSTR( LOCALTIMESTAMP::TEXT, 1, 13 )||':'|| CASE 
        WHEN date_part('minute', LOCALTIMESTAMP)  < 15 THEN '00' 
        WHEN date_part('minute', LOCALTIMESTAMP)  BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '15' 
        WHEN date_part('minute', LOCALTIMESTAMP)  BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30'
        ELSE '45' END||':00' 
    AS TIMESTAMP)
```